# Print comma separated data in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I have the following data:

```
label,callback,max-result,style
```

How to insert each item inside script tag? the result should be:

```
<div class='**STYLE**'><script src='/feeds/posts/summary/-/**LABEL**?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=**CALLBACK**&amp;max-results=**MAX-RESULT**' type='text/javascript'/></div>
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: You mean as attributes, right?

Comment: Yes! i think so... :) I'm not familiar with the terms yet but I want to learn.

Comment: As variables? Look up how to use JS variables inside HTML elements. Or maybe, as @TyQ. said, you mean to use em as attributes.

Comment: Something like Tamar's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id='data_here'>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
   var data="label,callback,max-result,style".split(",");
   var d = document.getElementById('data_here');
   d.className = data[3];
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script['src']="/feeds/posts/summary/-/"+data[0]+"?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback="+data[1]+"&amp;max-results="+data[2];
   d.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The logic seems easy to follow on my part. I tested it but there's no result.

Comment: The result should be like this right: <div id='data_here'><div class='style'><script src='/feeds/posts/summary/-/label?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=callback&amp;max-results=max-result' type='text/javascript'/></div>
</div> I tried to "inspect element" it but nothing is showing inside data_here div. you think jquery is better?

Comment: Your code is perfectly working. I can see the result if I "inspect element" it  but my problem is that It doesnt show on the browser... will it work if we use jquery?